# Keys lost in a water evacuation pipe

Tags: pipe

I lost my keys right in front of my building, in a water evacuation pipe of approximately 7-8 centimeters of diameter. It goes vertically in the ground for about 1m and then bend to approximately 90 degrees, which means this next part is almost horizontal. It is filled with small rocks. I guess my bunch of keys ended up at the beginning of this part.

None of the keys is magnetised. I tried to get them back using a wire with a hook at the end, but I didn't succeed, I guess the rocks are not helping. I am afraid using a drain cleaner would push them further instead of hooking them.

I have no other access to the pipe, and no direct vision on the bunch of keys.

Is anyone having an idea ? I'm getting a bit desperate here because it would cost me a lot if I can't get them back.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Borescope is your friend.... I have seen cheapies...

Comment: Boroscope + wire you recommend ? Because boroscope will let me see what's happening but not necessarily retrieve the keys

Comment: As Harper recommends a bore scope many come with hooks or mirrors that can attach to the end, or make a hook to attach to the end.+

Answer (score 2):

In desperation, I would likely use a shop vacuum, a wet-dry vacuum that can tolerate pulling out water without damaging the vacuum. It should also handle the small rocks.

Be sure to remove the paper filter if the instructions for the vacuum so state and to empty the bin prior to this operation.

Even if the keys will not pass into the vacuum hose, it may block the hose enough to use as a lifting device to retrieve them.

Comment: I am actually currently trying to get one from friends, to avoid buying one :) but the hose has to be long and flexible enough to go into the pipe, otherwise I'd need a very strong one that can pull everything out of the pipe on more than one vertical meter

Answer (score 0):

If the keys have a steel key ring i would try a magnet, otherwise you may need to call around to find a plumber that has camera that may be able to help.

Comment: They do but I tried on the spare bunch, which is almost exactly the same, and the magnets are not strong enough to grab them.
I thought about this possibility but I'm wondering if it would be cheaper than just make new ones (I'm living in France, plumber fees are quite high !).

Comment: There are some extremely strong magnets available here in the United States at hardware stores, but if you can't find a strong magnet, then unfortunately your options are limited. If you don't have copies of all the keys then you would also have the charge of a locksmith if you opt for making new keys.

Comment: I'm not even sure the rings are actually in steel, but that remains an option :)
And yeah, I would have the charge of a locksmith in this case. I just hope the landlord won't want to change the locks too...

Comment: the ring is almost assuredly steel, spring steel, maybe stainless. no other material makes physical+economic sense. a strong enough magnet WILL clasp the ring. even a weaker magnet can drag the keys to hook range...